# Reshaping the mean Matlab

Tags: matlab

This may be easy. I've got a variable that's (16x155). When I take the mean of that variable, it becomes (1x155). What I need it to be is (1x16). How do I do this?

Appreciate any tips!!

Comment: What you want to do might be taking mean of columns so you can wirte `mean(yourMatrix, 2)`.

Comment: THANK YOU - taking mean(yourmatrix,2) worked perfectly!

Comment: Okay... so this is weird. Why would I get the following error when using std(yourmatrix, 2)?   Error using var (line 94)
W must be a vector of nonnegative weights, or a scalar 0 or 1.

Error in std (line 31)
y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));

Comment: Second argument of the `std()` function is `flag` value so it takes  the value `0` or `1`, thus when you enter `2` as `flag` value, this cause runtime error. On the other hand for `mean()` function takes the value `1` (refers taking mean of rows, and this is the default value of the function) or the value `2` (refers taking mean of columns). Take a look at this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for std: `std(matrix, flag, dimension)`. In your case: `std(matrix, 0, 2)`

Syntax for mean: `mean(matrix, dimension)`. In your case: `mean(matrix, 2)`

Comment: @dbs - You can expand your answer includes mine, that is okay for me if you are concern.